# Configure Linux kernel and grub on external drive

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, grub

I'm moving my system from an old drive to a new one.

I could boot from a live CD/USB stick and install the system there, but for some weird reason the bios seems unable to do so.

So, how can I change from the old to the new drive and install GRUB and Linux there? Additionally, I would to setup-up this new drive with LUKS and LVM.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, you can find the details at: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system

It basically boils down to:

- Create a boot partition on /dev/sdb1
- Create a crypt-luks partion `enc` on /dev/sdb2
- Create a LVM `enc_my_lv` logical volume on top of the luks partition.
- Create a btrfs (or ext4) on `enc_my_lv`.
- Fsync system and user data from old drive to `enc_my_lv`.
- Edit fstab and cryptsetup to fit your new system.

Now the additional part not covered there is to manually install Grub and Linux on the boot partition:

Mount `enc_my_lv` on /mnt:

```
mount /dev/your_vg/enc_my_lv /mnt
```

Mount boot on /mnt/boot:

```
mkdir /mnt/boot
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/boot
```

Mount additional devices:

```
for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done  #(credits: see https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/232047)
```

Chroot to /mnt and run configs:

```
chroot /mnt
dpkg -l | grep linux-image-.*-generic | sort -k3 | tail -n1 | awk '{system ("sudo apt-get install --reinstall " $2)}' #Reinstall Linux kernel packages there (credits: see https://askubuntu.com/a/298855/232047)
update-initramfs -u
grub-install /dev/sdb
update-grub
```